# How do filters in conv1 of alexnet prefer certain colors?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, pytorch, conv-neural-network

If you look at the filters in alexnet conv1, many of them have bright bands or dots of color. However, I thought that the rgb values were put into alexnet as 3 separate channels, and identical filters were used for each channel. In other words, I don't see how a filter could prefer one color over another. Can anyone explain this?

[image of alexnet filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0UHA.png)

Answer (score 0):

"identical filters were used for each channel" -> not true.

Each input channel has its own set of filters. These sets are then put into RGB images as visualizations that you are showing.